# why my makefile works with asterisk as wildcard, but do not with percentage?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my makefile:

```
default: *.s
   echo $(basename $<)
```

Does echo the basename, but

```
default: %.s
   echo $(basename $<)
```

outputs:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '%.s', needed by 'default'.  Stop.
```

I have `smf.s` file in directory, where the makefile is. So why do not makefile use it as Prerequisite? (only shell-like `*` does, but `%` does not), why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule:

```
default: *.s
   echo $(basename $<)
```

works as you expect because `*` is a [wildcard character](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html) in GNU Make.

On the other hand, your second rule:

```
default: %.s
   echo $(basename $<)
```

has `%.s` as a prerequisite. Since there is no file named `%.s` Make needs an additional rule to generate this missing file `%.s`. That is what the error message is about:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '%.s', needed by 'default'.  Stop.
```

---

You may think that `%` is a wildcard character. Actually, it behaves as such in [*pattern rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html). However, your second rule isn't a pattern rule. The following is an excerpt from the documentation:

> A pattern rule looks like an ordinary rule, except that **its target contains the character ‘%’** (exactly one of them).

Your second rule's target – i.e., `default` – does not contain the character `%`. Therefore, it can't be qualified as a pattern rule, so the `%` in the prerequisite, `%.s`, is literally the `%` character.

Comment: But, the '%' is also wildcard, otherwise it would not be use as `%.o: %.c \n\t gcc .....`